# How to change explorer tree style

Tags: visual-studio-code

I do not like the style of the explorer. It’s hard to see which folders are open, they all merge. I prefer the style of the tree from the atom or phpstorm editor but I can’t find where to change this style.
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's an open issue to draw indent guides: [#17777](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/17777)

[image]

---

From something that's already implemented is indent size (in `Settings`):

```json
"workbench.tree.indent": 40
```

Comment: thank so much, and how did you make these lines in front of the folders?

Comment: It's not implemented. That's why the issue is **open**.

Comment: I can't seem to find how to make that horizontal lines appear. I can only see vertical indenting lines. Is that some kind of special feature of specific theme?

Comment: Nope. They made it without horizontal lines :(